# Web reference call return object with null fields

Tags: asp.net, web-services, namespaces, wsdl

I know this is a repeated problem. But I've Googled in the last 2 days, but still can not find the solution to my issue. The popular answer is namespace related but it still does not help me.

Ok, so my wsdl is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- WSDL for http://daac.ornl.gov/cgi-bin/MODIS/GLBVIZ_1_Glb_subset/MODIS_webservice.pl created by Pod::WSDL version: 0.04 on Mon May 24 15:41:43 2010 -->
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice" 
              xmlns:impl="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice" 
              xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
              xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
              xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
              xmlns:tns1="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice">

<wsdl:types>
    <schema targetNamespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        <complexType name="ArrayOfString">
            <complexContent>
                <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                    <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="soapenc:string[]" />
                </restriction>
            </complexContent>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="ModisData">
            <sequence>
                <element name="xllcorner" nillable="true" type="xsd:float">
                    <annotation>
                        <documentation>
                        X-Longitude of the corner of lower left pixel in Sinusoidal projection
                        </documentation>
                    </annotation>
                </element>
                <element name="yllcorner" nillable="true" type="xsd:float">
                    <annotation>
                <documentation>
                Y-Latitude of the corner of lower left pixel in Sinusoidal projection
                </documentation>
                    </annotation>
                </element>
                <element name="cellsize" nillable="true" type="xsd:float">
                    <annotation>
                <documentation>Resolution of the data</documentation>
                    </annotation>
                </element>
                <element name="nrows" nillable="true" type="xsd:float">
                    <annotation>
                <documentation>Number of rows</documentation>
                    </annotation>
                </element>
                <element name="ncols" nillable="true" type="xsd:float">
                    <annotation>
                <documentation>Number of rows</documentation>
                    </annotation>
                </element>
                <element name="band" nillable="true" type="xsd:string">
                    <annotation>
                        <documentation>Band Name</documentation>
                    </annotation>
                </element>
                <element name="units" nillable="true" type="xsd:string">
                    <annotation>
                        <documentation>Units for the band</documentation>
                    </annotation>
                </element>
                <element name="scale" nillable="true" type="xsd:float">
                    <annotation>
                        <documentation>scale of the data values</documentation>
                    </annotation>
                </element>
                <element name="latitude" nillable="true" type="xsd:float">
                    <annotation>
                        <documentation>Latitude in degrees of the subset location</documentation>
                    </annotation>
                </element>
                <element name="longitude" nillable="true" type="xsd:float">
                    <annotation>
                        <documentation>Longitude in degrees of the subset location</documentation>
                    </annotation>
                </element>
                <element name="header" nillable="true" type="xsd:string">
                    <annotation>
                        <documentation>Header for the Subset returned</documentation>
                    </annotation>
                </element>
                <element name="subset" nillable="true" type="tns1:ArrayOfString">
                    <annotation>
                        <documentation>Subset data</documentation>
                    </annotation>
                </element>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="getproductsRequest">
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="getproductsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getproductsReturn" type="tns1:ArrayOfString">
        <wsdl:documentation>This returns the list of products available. Product shortname is used.</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="getbandsRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="Product" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>MODIS Product Shortname</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="getbandsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getbandsReturn" type="tns1:ArrayOfString">
        <wsdl:documentation>This returns the list of bands available for a product</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="getdatesRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="Latitude" type="xsd:float">
        <wsdl:documentation>Latitude in geographic Lat/Long WGS 84 coordinate system</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="Longitude" type="xsd:float">
        <wsdl:documentation>Longitude in geographic Lat/Long WGS 84 coordinate system</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="Product" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>MODIS Product Shortname</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="getdatesResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getdatesReturn" type="tns1:ArrayOfString">
        <wsdl:documentation>This returns the list of composite dates available for the product,Latitude,Longitude combination</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="getsubsetRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="Latitude" type="xsd:float">
        <wsdl:documentation>Latitude in geographic Lat/Long WGS 84 coordinate system</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="Longitude" type="xsd:float">
        <wsdl:documentation>Longitude in geographic Lat/Long WGS 84 coordinate system</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="Product" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>MODIS Product Shortname</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="Band" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>Enter the band you want to retreive. Enter all to get all bands.</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="MODIS_Subset_Start_Date" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>MODIS Composite Date Start of the Subset period</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="MODIS_Subset_End_Date" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>MODIS Composite Date End of the Subset period</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="Km_Above_Below" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>Size in km of the subset above and below the center location</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="Km_Left_Right" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>Size in km of the subset left and right the center location</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="getsubsetResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getsubsetReturn" type="tns1:ModisData">
        <wsdl:documentation>This returns the subset for the location,product and date combination and detailed projection information.</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="getsubsetorderRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="Latitude" type="xsd:float">
        <wsdl:documentation>Latitude in geographic Lat/Long WGS 84 coordinate system</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="Longitude" type="xsd:float">
        <wsdl:documentation>Longitude in geographic Lat/Long WGS 84 coordinate system</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="Product" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>MODIS Product Shortname</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="Email" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>Enter the email address to which you want to receive the order</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="UID" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>Unique tag for the order</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="MODIS_Subset_Start_Date" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>MODIS Composite Date Start of the Subset period</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="MODIS_Subset_End_Date" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>MODIS Composite Date End of the Subset period</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="Km_Above_Below" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>Size in km of the subset above and below the center location</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="Km_Left_Right" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>Size in km of the subset left and right the center location</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="getsubsetorderResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getsubsetorderReturn" type="xsd:string">
        <wsdl:documentation>This returns the order ID for the subset ID. An email with a link to the subset order would be dispatched to the email address provided.</wsdl:documentation>
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="myServiceHandler">
    <wsdl:operation name="getproducts" parameterOrder="">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getproductsRequest" name="getproductsRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getproductsResponse" name="getproductsResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="getbands" parameterOrder="Product">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getbandsRequest" name="getbandsRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getbandsResponse" name="getbandsResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="getdates" parameterOrder="Latitude Longitude Product">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getdatesRequest" name="getdatesRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getdatesResponse" name="getdatesResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="getsubset" parameterOrder="Latitude Longitude Product Band MODIS_Subset_Start_Date MODIS_Subset_End_Date Km_Above_Below Km_Left_Right">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getsubsetRequest" name="getsubsetRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getsubsetResponse" name="getsubsetResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="getsubsetorder" parameterOrder="Latitude Longitude Product Email UID MODIS_Subset_Start_Date MODIS_Subset_End_Date Km_Above_Below Km_Left_Right">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getsubsetorderRequest" name="getsubsetorderRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getsubsetorderResponse" name="getsubsetorderResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="myServiceSoapBinding" type="impl:myServiceHandler">
    <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

    <wsdl:operation name="getproducts">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
        <wsdl:input name="getproductsRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice" use="encoded" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getproductsResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice" use="encoded" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="getbands">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
        <wsdl:input name="getbandsRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice" use="encoded" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getbandsResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice" use="encoded" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="getdates">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
        <wsdl:input name="getdatesRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice" use="encoded" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getdatesResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice" use="encoded" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="getsubset">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
        <wsdl:input name="getsubsetRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice" use="encoded" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getsubsetResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice" use="encoded" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="getsubsetorder">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
        <wsdl:input name="getsubsetorderRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice" use="encoded" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getsubsetorderResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice" use="encoded" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="myServiceHandlerService">
    <wsdl:port binding="impl:myServiceSoapBinding" name="myService">
        <wsdlsoap:address location="http://daac.ornl.gov/cgi-bin/MODIS/GLBVIZ_1_Glb_subset/MODIS_webservice.pl" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

My generated proxy class is:

```
namespace FarmNet.Modis {
// .... I cut off code
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="myServiceSoapBinding", Namespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice")]
public partial class myServiceHandlerService : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {

   // ........... code cut off
    /// <remarks/>
    public myServiceHandlerService() {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice", ResponseNamespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice")]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("getproductsReturn")]
    public string[] getproducts() {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("getproducts", new object[0]);
        return ((string[])(results[0]));
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void getproductsAsync() {
        this.getproductsAsync(null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void getproductsAsync(object userState) {
        if ((this.getproductsOperationCompleted == null)) {
            this.getproductsOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OngetproductsOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("getproducts", new object[0], this.getproductsOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OngetproductsOperationCompleted(object arg) {
        if ((this.getproductsCompleted != null)) {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.getproductsCompleted(this, new getproductsCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice", ResponseNamespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice")]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("getbandsReturn")]
    public string[] getbands(string Product) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("getbands", new object[] {
                    Product});
        return ((string[])(results[0]));
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void getbandsAsync(string Product) {
        this.getbandsAsync(Product, null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void getbandsAsync(string Product, object userState) {
        if ((this.getbandsOperationCompleted == null)) {
            this.getbandsOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OngetbandsOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("getbands", new object[] {
                    Product}, this.getbandsOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OngetbandsOperationCompleted(object arg) {
        if ((this.getbandsCompleted != null)) {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.getbandsCompleted(this, new getbandsCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice", ResponseNamespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice")]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("getdatesReturn")]
    public string[] getdates(float Latitude, float Longitude, string Product) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("getdates", new object[] {
                    Latitude,
                    Longitude,
                    Product});
        return ((string[])(results[0]));
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void getdatesAsync(float Latitude, float Longitude, string Product) {
        this.getdatesAsync(Latitude, Longitude, Product, null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void getdatesAsync(float Latitude, float Longitude, string Product, object userState) {
        if ((this.getdatesOperationCompleted == null)) {
            this.getdatesOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OngetdatesOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("getdates", new object[] {
                    Latitude,
                    Longitude,
                    Product}, this.getdatesOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OngetdatesOperationCompleted(object arg) {
        if ((this.getdatesCompleted != null)) {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.getdatesCompleted(this, new getdatesCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice", ResponseNamespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice")]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("getsubsetReturn")]
    public ModisData getsubset(float Latitude, float Longitude, string Product, string Band, string MODIS_Subset_Start_Date, string MODIS_Subset_End_Date, string Km_Above_Below, string Km_Left_Right) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("getsubset", new object[] {
                    Latitude,
                    Longitude,
                    Product,
                    Band,
                    MODIS_Subset_Start_Date,
                    MODIS_Subset_End_Date,
                    Km_Above_Below,
                    Km_Left_Right});
        return ((ModisData)(results[0]));
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void getsubsetAsync(float Latitude, float Longitude, string Product, string Band, string MODIS_Subset_Start_Date, string MODIS_Subset_End_Date, string Km_Above_Below, string Km_Left_Right) {
        this.getsubsetAsync(Latitude, Longitude, Product, Band, MODIS_Subset_Start_Date, MODIS_Subset_End_Date, Km_Above_Below, Km_Left_Right, null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void getsubsetAsync(float Latitude, float Longitude, string Product, string Band, string MODIS_Subset_Start_Date, string MODIS_Subset_End_Date, string Km_Above_Below, string Km_Left_Right, object userState) {
        if ((this.getsubsetOperationCompleted == null)) {
            this.getsubsetOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OngetsubsetOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("getsubset", new object[] {
                    Latitude,
                    Longitude,
                    Product,
                    Band,
                    MODIS_Subset_Start_Date,
                    MODIS_Subset_End_Date,
                    Km_Above_Below,
                    Km_Left_Right}, this.getsubsetOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OngetsubsetOperationCompleted(object arg) {
        if ((this.getsubsetCompleted != null)) {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.getsubsetCompleted(this, new getsubsetCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

   // Code is cut off
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice")]
public partial class ModisData {

    private System.Nullable<float> xllcornerField;

    private System.Nullable<float> yllcornerField;

    private System.Nullable<float> cellsizeField;

    private System.Nullable<float> nrowsField;

    private System.Nullable<float> ncolsField;

    private string bandField;

    private string unitsField;

    private System.Nullable<float> scaleField;

    private System.Nullable<float> latitudeField;

    private System.Nullable<float> longitudeField;

    private string headerField;

    private string[] subsetField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<float> xllcorner {
        get {
            return this.xllcornerField;
        }
        set {
            this.xllcornerField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<float> yllcorner {
        get {
            return this.yllcornerField;
        }
        set {
            this.yllcornerField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<float> cellsize {
        get {
            return this.cellsizeField;
        }
        set {
            this.cellsizeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<float> nrows {
        get {
            return this.nrowsField;
        }
        set {
            this.nrowsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<float> ncols {
        get {
            return this.ncolsField;
        }
        set {
            this.ncolsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string band {
        get {
            return this.bandField;
        }
        set {
            this.bandField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string units {
        get {
            return this.unitsField;
        }
        set {
            this.unitsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<float> scale {
        get {
            return this.scaleField;
        }
        set {
            this.scaleField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<float> latitude {
        get {
            return this.latitudeField;
        }
        set {
            this.latitudeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<float> longitude {
        get {
            return this.longitudeField;
        }
        set {
            this.longitudeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string header {
        get {
            return this.headerField;
        }
        set {
            this.headerField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string[] subset {
        get {
            return this.subsetField;
        }
        set {
            this.subsetField = value;
        }
    }
 // Code is cut off
}
```

Now all the functions: `getproducts()`, `getdates()`, `getbands()` are all working correctly. The only function that does not work is `getsubset()`. I use Fiddler and see the soap response received correctly as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns1="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice">
    <soap:Body>
        <getsubsetResponse xmlns="http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS_webservice">
            <tns1:getsubsetReturn xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="tns1:ModisData">
                <xllcorner xsi:type="xsd:float">12900942.51</xllcorner>
                <yllcorner xsi:type="xsd:float">-3785264.93</yllcorner>
                <cellsize xsi:type="xsd:float">463.312716528</cellsize>
                <nrows xsi:type="xsd:float">21</nrows>
                <ncols xsi:type="xsd:float">21</ncols>
                <band xsi:type="xsd:string">LC_Property_1</band>
                <units xsi:type="xsd:string">Not Available</units>
                <scale xsi:type="xsd:float">0</scale>
                <latitude xsi:type="xsd:float">-34</latitude>
                <longitude xsi:type="xsd:float">140</longitude>
                <header xsi:type="xsd:string">HDFname,...     </header>
                <subset soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">MCD12Q1.A2001001....</item>
                </subset>
            </tns1:getsubsetReturn>
        </getsubsetResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My code-behind, where I call the web service:

```
myServiceHandlerClient o = new myServiceHandlerClient();
// This WORKS:
string[] products = o.getproducts();
// This does NOT work, data is returned with all null fields:
ModisData data = o.getsubset(-34, 140, "MCD12Q1", "LC_Property_1", "A2001001", "A2001001", "5", "5");
```

Ok, so from my research there can be a mismatch in namespace, but I cant find it. The namespace in the wsdl file and the namespace from the soap response are the same(that's why all other functions work). Also, I dont see any typo or anything wrong with the element names either.

What can be wrong here? Please help.

ps: I even tried to use WCF by adding service reference from visual studio to generate the proxy class. However, none of the functions work, they all return null.

Comment: Can you add something specific about _what_ is broken, where? I didn't find anything along the lines of "this `<foo>` should instead be `<bar>`" -- I'm completely lost about what the actual problem is.

Comment: hi sarnold, i've edited to show where code is broken. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can some one have a look into this problem and give a hand? For now I have to intercept the soap response and parse it manually.

Comment: Hrm, that WSDL was generated 1.5 years ago -- are you sure the API still provides that function? Are you certain it is intended for public use? (Sometimes APIs are automatically generated but not all interfaces are the same maturity level...)